# An interface receives packet with wrong local destination

Tags: routing

I think my question is very simple. Assume that I have a router or a computer with turned on routing. The device has 2 interfaces and see two networks.
For example, `192.168.0.2 eth0` and `10.0.0.2 eth1`. Locally I have nginx on `192.168.0.2:80`. I undestand that if **eth1** receives packet with destination `192.168.0.3` it will be forwarded to `eth0`. But what if `192.168.0.2:80`? Will it be forwarded to nginx? Or will it be dropped? What rules will kernel use to handle this situation?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/492217/6622

Comment: I don't know about host model. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Eth1 can't receive 192.168.0.2:80 only if it is a gateway or a hop for the one which sends the package. In that case if you have IP forwarding enabled in kernel and masquerading for the interface you will be able to let traffic pass through interface eth1 and finally reach 192.168.0.2:80, your destination.

Comment: Thanks for response! I've read more about [host model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_model). As far as I understand you do not need masquerading if model is weak. So in my case (weak model) kernel should accept packet with local dst 192.168.0.2 on interface 10.0.0.2.